# Python Cannot install requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm

I am trying to install requests module in PyCharm.
I tried every commands on StackOverflow but still got errors below -

> command: sudo pip3 install requests
> Error: ERROR: Could not find a
> version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip3

I also try pip because I have pip package installed in my python interpreter but still has error -

> command: sudo pip install requests
> Error: sudo: pip: command not found

I also tried to install requests package and `easy_install` in python interpreter but still got Error when installing package.

Comment: have you tried just using pip instead of pip3 and is pip even installed on your system?

Comment: The recommended way to envoke pip is with `python3 -m pip` rather than with `pip3` because... well, I don't know why they're doing this to us.

Comment: Have you setupped PyCharm with python-venv? In each case (if I'm not wrong) the package `requests` is pre-installed on python3.

Comment: @simonecocco `urllib3` comes preinstalled because `pip` depends on it.  `requests` is usually not included

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN calling `pip` or `pip3` directly relies on a bunch of assumptions, including that you have correct executables in your `PATH`. This can be tricky in many ways, e.g. if you have multiple versions of `python3` installed. `python<ver> -m pip` is prone safe to all these edge cases

Comment: why are you trying to install this as root?  you should probably just do it as the individual user account, like `pip install --user requests`